# passing value from activity to adapter

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am devloping an app in which when user enter their mail id, i am storing that in a varible and passing to other activity.
For this i am using navigation drawer,in that from main activity i am passing the email to another activity that is internShips.In that i am passing  the value by using its position:as shown below:

```
         mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                                long arg3) {
if(position==3)
            {
               Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,internships.class) ;
                intent.putExtra("email", email);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

In internships i am using recyclerview .In that if i click on any item it will start another activity.For clicking item i am giving clicking option in internshipAdapter as shown below:

```
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {


          Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), InternShipsDetails.class);

            String email = i.getStringExtra("email");
            i.putExtra("email" , email);
            v.getContext().startActivity(i);

        }
    });
}
```

and in other activity i am getting the value using intent as shown below:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String email=intent.getStringExtra("email");
```

But the problem is, the value for email is showing null.So,where i am wrong,help here.

Comment: `String email = i.getStringExtra("email");` how is `i` defined here ?

Comment: Specify in `holder` where you defined `i` for `i.getStringExtra("email")`?

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), InternShipsDetails.class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Change your code as this inside `holder onClick`. Because you are using `intent` for which you are changing your activity. So you need to use `getIntent()` to get `email` value.

```
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), InternShipsDetails.class);
Intent emailIntent = ((Activity)v.getContext()).getIntent();
String email = emailIntent.getStringExtra("email");
i.putExtra("email" , email);
Log.d("###$email", email + "");

v.getContext().startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Right, he'll also need the reference of the activity to call `getIntent()`

Comment: got it..we should write like this:  ((Activity)v.getContext()).getIntent();

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), InternShipsDetails.class)`
use the context you should be passing to the adapter (The activity that the adapter is set in) and do like this:

```
Intent i = new Intent(context, InternShipsDetails.class);
```